# No results using debug() in AJAX calls

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm making jQuery Mobile app with Cake 2.0 but having trouble submitting a form to the controller actions.

It seems like form is submitting but I'm not getting any results when I do `debug($this->request->data)`.

Is this because it's submitting as AJAX? If so, how can I solve it so that I can receive form inputs to my controller and return them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**debug** should show the data and its not dependent on request type, you need to have appropriate value in your **Config/Core.php** like:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2); // in your Core.php file

//then in your Controller's some function
$this->layout = "ajax";
if($this->request->is("ajax")) {
   debug($this->request->data); // should display all your request data
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->request->data
```

is used to access POSTed data.

```
$this->request->query
```

is used to display your GET data

Make sure that your Ajax calls are made using POST and not GET if you want to keep using `$this->request->data`. If you want to view the entire request object, simply `debug()` on `$this->request` instead.

Good luck!